# iOS SDK: How to get the date out of a UIDatePicker?

Tags: iphone

I need to retrieve the date from a UIDatePicker (Preferably I would also like to be specify the format as well. For example, mmdd would output the string 1209. Any string that reasonably parsed would work as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to use the date property:

```
NSDate *myDate = datePicker.date;

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"cccc, MMM d, hh:mm aa"];
NSString *prettyVersion = [dateFormat stringFromDate:myDate];
```

BTW, it's not obvious but you can add specific non-parsed text by encompassing it inside single quotes in the format:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"'Game-'yyyyMMdd-HHmm'.xml'"];
NSString *filenameVersion = [dateFormat stringFromDate:myDate];
```

Comment: I have a problem with this, don't know how.
Here's my code (i wrote before I saw the answer):
`NSDateFormatter *formate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    
    UILocalNotification *ln = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    NSDate *settedDate = self.myPickedDate.date;
    formate.dateFormat = @"dd.MMM.yyyy @ HH:mm:ss";
    
    NSString *dateString = [formate stringFromDate:settedDate];
    NSLog(@"datestring: %@", dateString);`

It shows me the current date, not the date I have set in UIDatePicker.

Comment: how to you retrieve the date while respecting the user's device date format preference? seems that manually setting a dateFormat will override the user's device settings.